# filter data from one table based on second table without duplicates

Tags: database, ms-access, filter, subforms

*Note: I'm working with a large complex database, so for clarity's sake I have simplified the set up below.*

I struggled a bit with how to title the question since it's a bit of a complex question. I hope it's accurate enough....

**A bit of background first:**

I have an Access 2010 database that contains a one-to-many relationship between a table Called "Products" and a table called "Datasets" (ie I have a bunch of products, and each product has multiple datasets). Each has an autonumber key field (p_ID and d_ID respectively) as well as numerous other fields.

I have a form (lets call it frm_Main) that has two subforms: sub_Products (based on the "Products" table) and sub_Datasets (based on the "Datasets" table). On the main form I have a control ctrl_SelectedProduct which is linked to [sub_Products]![p_ID] to see which record in sub_Products is selected / has the focus, and the sub_Datasets subform is linked to this control so that it only displays Datasets records that belong to the selected Products record.

On the main form I also have a number of controls that I'm using for filtering the data in the subforms. For example, I have a control ctrl_Category. I have this control coded so that when the user changes the value of the control, a filter is applied that limits the records in sub_Products to only those that have a p_Category value equal to whatever is chosen in ctrl_Category. If the control is blank, it will show all records. All this works great when if comes to filtering based on fields in the Products table.

**Now the problem:**

My problem is that I also want to be able to filter based on fields in the Datasets table. For example, Datasets has a field called d_Status. I want the user to be able to chose the status in a control (ctrl_Status), and based on this:

**1)** sub_Products will be filtered to display only those Products records that have an assotiated Datasets record (or records) that has d_Status equal to whatever was chosen in ctrl_Status

then

**2)** when a Products record is selected in this filtered sub_Products, sub_Datasets will only show the Datasets records that has d_Status equal to whatever was chosen in ctrl_Status

I know how to do part2. But I have no idea how to get part1 to work. Since sub_Products is currently based on the Products table, which does not have the d_Status field, I have no way to filter it based on that field. Thus, I'm assuming my first step will be to change my setup so that sub_Products is based on a query that combines the two tables (or at least adds the d_Status field).

If I do that, however, I get duplicate Product records. I can't use the query's Unique Values property because if I have a product that has two datasets, one with status "Current" and a one with status "Archived", then those aren't considered duplicates, and the product info is there twice. If I don't have the status field displayed, it shows only unique products initially, but then I can't subsequently apply a filter based on that non-displayed field.

I also tried basing sub_Products on a Totals query in order to utilize the Group By functionality, but I still couldn't get it to work right. Even if I could I don't think that's the best solution, because you can only have 10 fields with Group By, and my Products table has more than 10 fields that I need displayed in sub_Products.

I feel like I'm now just going around in circles and am at a loss of what to try from here. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't you add something like this?

```
Private Sub ctrl_Category_AfterUpdate()
    Form_frm_Main.Recordsource = "Select * from Products where p_ID IN(" & _
                                 "Select p_ID from Datasets where d_Status = " & _
                                 Me!ctrl_Category.Value & ")"
End Sub
```

Alternately, you can access the childform via the parent of the other child form.
This is a non-working snippet just to give you the idea:

```
Me.Parent.otherChildFormName.Form.Recordsource = whatever
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel! It looks like changing the Recordsource instead of applying a filter was the key.  Of course that means I'll now have to change my Audit Trail coding (it was getting the source table by looking at Recordsource), but that's better than doing a complete redesign of my subforms!